# Алгоритм изменения цвета изображения на canvas

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, canvas

Здравствуйте. Занимаюсь разработкой сервиса по подбору цветов для лакокрасочного предприятия. Перекрашивать нужно изображения дома внутри и снаружи.

Для перекраски изображения использую несколько canvas. Один canvas — оригинальное изображение и по одному для каждого элемента (к примеру для пола, стены, окна, забота и т.д.) на этом canvas расположена только часть изображения.

В настоящий момент разработал такой алгоритм:

1. Переводим цвет, в который нужно перекрасить в HSV.
2. Беру каждый пиксель в canvas на котором расположена часть изображения и записываю количество значений «V» * 100 в объект (для того что бы округлить и получить статистику).
3. После предыдущего шага получаю объект в котором содержатся количество вхождений значений «V». Нахожу максимальное значение в этом объекте — тем самым получаю основной цвет изображения.
4. Перекрашиваю каждый пиксель части изображения используя «H» и «S» из шага 1, а «V» получаю по формуле (V шага 1 + (V пикселя оригинального изображения - V максимального в части изображения)).

В моём алгоритме есть несколько проблем:

1. Если изображение не монотонное, то может получится что параметр «V» найденый на 3 шаге не совсем основной цвет изображения из-за того что может быть несколько максимумов (отличным примером является рисунок паркета — там смешиваются светлые и тёмные цвета) — они будут например в V = 10 и V = 90 и в 10 немного больше чем в 90 и тогда изображение на выходе получается блеклым.
2. Если перекрашиваем например в белый цвет, а V = 10, то текстура получается очень светлой и наоборот если текстура очень тёмная, то на выходе получается чёрный цвет.

В настоящий момент устанавливаю параметр из 3 пункта в ручную, но подбор такой мне не нравится.

Если у Вас есть желание помочь с алгоритмом, размять мозги или просто подсказать работающее решении буду рад обсуждению.

Пример кода: http://kvil.goodsol10.tmweb.ru/repair-school/color-service/color/Test2.php

Не могу вставить его из-за ограничений. 
Там видно как изображение перекрашивается в фиолетовый. Проблемная область — плинтус и пол. Проблема в том что при правильной перекраске цвет плинтуса и пола должны быть более насыщенные.

Comment: Не совсем понятно - что происходит. Понятнее было бы со скриншотами - работа с графикой всё-таки. Вообще алгоритмов перекрашивания куча - только непонятно, что конкретно надо тебе. Добавь скрины вида "исходное изображение" -> "как надо". Я бы посоветовал исходное изображение обесцветить, а потом наложить цветовую маску.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр  Добавил пример кода. Там видно как изображение перекрашивается в фиолетовый. Проблемная область — плинтус и пол. Проблема в том что при правильной перекраске цвет плинтуса и пола должны быть более насыщенные.

Comment: А кстати, заранее нафотошопленные варианты не рассматривали? Чтобы не делать кучу комбинаций, можно отдельно сохранить каждый элемент в во всех возможных цветах (используя автоматизацию уже на уровне фотошопа). Это избавит от тормозов, и потенциально даст более высокое качество.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian несколько тысяч возможных цветов для перекраски. Это нереально отфотошопить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В простом случае - когда тестуры оттеночные(а не рельефные/бликовые карты) - они смешиваются сложением или умножением(или комбинацией сложения и умножения) rgba компонент (где каждая из компонент от 0 до 1).

Ошибка в твоём случае(по моему мнению) - это вычисление общей яркости объекта, она не должна влиять на конечное изображение.

Если есть сложности с подбором алгоритма - можно старый добрый фотошоп открыть, и проэмулировать то, что хочется применить к изображению, а затем перенести в алгоритм.

Помимо этого, думаю - для каждого из объектов (пол, плинтус, и.т.п) - следует ввести коррекционные параметры: яркость, контрастность, насыщенность. У каждого объекта цифры увеличения/уменьшения свои. Применять коррекцию - после наложения цвета. [Вот соответсвующие формулы постобработки](http://www.dfstudios.co.uk/articles/programming/image-programming-algorithms/)

Возможно вопрос состоит в том - чтобы эти коррекционные параметры автоматически вычислять (для этого ты видимо и считал среднюю яркость) - но тут боюсь автоматически не получится, потому что в сервисе по продаже красок  - важна точность наложения краски, иначе разъярённые клиенты атакуют :)

И ещё - то что в примере тормозит сильно. JS и canvas не настолько медленные.

Comment: Тормозит JS — получается происходит 12 проходов по массивам с 1748*2400 = 4 200 000*4 элементов

Comment: @Mihanik71 возможно более продвинутые способы наложения помогут - шейдеры например https://www.sitepoint.com/mean-shaders-create-html5-webgl/ . Потом - цвет не обязательно перезаписывать в canvas - при таких расширениях - можно его как маску использовать. Есть ещё постпроцессинг фильтры в HTML5 https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter (держат все кроме конечно IE у которого свой синтаксис этих фильтров) - можно было бы без canvas-только ими обойтись: они работают быстро.

Comment: @В настоящий момент вывод делаю 1200 на 960 — очень большой выигрыш в производительности получается + пришлось отказаться от поиска цветности «на лету» и приходится указывать параметр при загрузке. Я просто хотел сделать универсальный инструмент, который можно подготовить целиком и выложить, но пока думаем ещё над алгоритмом и если что при загрузке будет ползунок, которым можно будет менять параметры

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна производительность, пользуйтесь блендингом Canvas.

Например, понизить яркость можно просто нарисовав поверх текущего изображения
в режиме ["difference"](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#blendingdifference) серый прямоугольник на столько яркий, сколько надо вычесть.

Для повышения яркости нужно изощриться чуть больше (почему-то API не дали метода "summary"), тогда проводите difference на предварительно инвертированном оригинале, затем инвертируете результат.

Для инверсии рисуйте оригинал поверх белого тем же difference
(математичеки казалось должно быть можно короче, но нет, потому что отрицательные значения обрезаются и невозможно подготовить такой исходник чтобы differense случился с текстурой в которой отрицательные значения. Приходиться играться со знаками).

Описанная процедура, даже в случае тройного рисования (для повышения яркости) будет быстрее, чем перебирать JS'ом попиксельно (потому что она вообще ускоряется нативно).